# Understanding an exponential inequality

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Given $a,b \in (0,1)$ such that $a^a > b^b$, there exists $\epsilon \in (0,\min(a,b))$ such that:

\begin{equation}
(a+\epsilon)^a+(b-\epsilon)^b > a^a +b^b
\end{equation}

So far I have found numerical evidence for this inequality but haven't been able to demonstrate it analytically. Is there a method for demonstrating such a result which doesn't involve lengthy calculations?

**Update**: Removed $a+b \leq 1$ condition as it is unnecessary.

Comment: Differentiate with respect to $\epsilon$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Daniel suggested, we can define
$$
 f(x) = (a+x)^a + (b-x)^b \quad \text{for } 0 \le x < \min(a, b) \,.
$$ 
$f$ is differentiable and
$$
 f'(x) = a(a+x)^{a-1} - b(b-x)^{b-1} \\
 f'(0) = a^a - b^b > 0 \, .
$$
$f'$ is continuous, therefore $f'(x) > 0$ (and $f$ strictly increasing) on some interval $[0, \varepsilon]$ with $\varepsilon > 0$.

The condition $a + b \le 1$ is not necessary.